# Implement custom section with a Configuration Element Collection c#

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, configuration-files

I would like to implement a custom configuration section in a project. But something I don't understand so dont work.

I have App.config that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="DepartmentConfigurationSection" type="Statistics.Config.DepartmentSection , Program1"/>
  </configSections>
  <s>
    <Cash>
      <add Number="1" Name="Money" />
    </Cash>
    <Departments>
      <add Id="1" Name="x" />
      <add Id="2" Name="y" />
    </Departments>
  </s>
</configuration>
```

I create a file called **DepartmentSection.cs** that cointains the ConfigurationElement,ConfigurationElementCollection and the ConfigurationSection.
The class is like this:

```
 public class DepartmentConfig : ConfigurationElement
    {
        public DepartmentConfig() { }

        public DepartmentConfig(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Id", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return (int)this["Id"]; }
            set { this["Id"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Name",  IsRequired = true, IsKey = false)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)this["Name"]; }
            set { this["Name"] = value; }
        }
    }


    public class DepartmentCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        public DepartmentCollection()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ServiceCollection Constructor");
        }

        public DepartmentConfig this[int index]
        {
            get { return (DepartmentConfig)BaseGet(index); }
            set
            {
                if (BaseGet(index) != null)
                {
                    BaseRemoveAt(index);
                }
                BaseAdd(index, value);
            }
        }

        public void Add(DepartmentConfig depConfig)
        {
            BaseAdd(depConfig);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            BaseClear();
        }

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new DepartmentConfig();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((DepartmentConfig)element).Id;
        }

        public void Remove(DepartmentConfig depConfig)
        {
            BaseRemove(depConfig.Id);
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            BaseRemoveAt(index);
        }

        public void Remove(string name)
        {
            BaseRemove(name);
        }
    }


    public class DepartmentConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("Departments", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
        [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(DepartmentCollection),
            AddItemName = "add",
            ClearItemsName = "clear",
            RemoveItemName = "remove")]
        public DepartmentCollection Departments
        {
            get
            {
                return (DepartmentCollection)base["Departments"];
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to get the collection from the handler but without success. I tried like this but give me this error: "Unable to initialize the system configuration".

```
    DepartmentConfigurationSection serviceConfigSection =
    ConfigurationManager.GetSection("s") as DepartmentConfigurationSection;

    DepartmentConfig serviceConfig = serviceConfigSection.Departments[0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems appear to be in your `app.config` (or `web.config`). The element that contains your custom configuration XML must match the name you have specified in the `name` attribute in `configSections\section`. For example, for your code to work as written, the app.config should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="s" type="Statistics.Config.DepartmentConfigurationSection, Program1"/>
  </configSections>
  <s>
    <Cash>
      <add Number="1" Name="Money" />
    </Cash>
    <Departments>
      <add Id="1" Name="x" />
      <add Id="2" Name="y" />
    </Departments>
  </s>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, the `section name="s"` matches the name of the `s` element. Also, you had the type listed as `Statistics.Config.DeptartmentSection`, but your class name is `DepartmentConfigurationSection`, so it should match the class you are trying to load.

Comment: I corrected the errors but now appares this: " Error while creating the configuration section handler for s: Could not load type 'Program1.Config.DepartmentConfigurationSection' from assembly 'Program1'... Why?

Comment: That means there's no class `Program1.Config.DepartmentConfigurationSection` in the `Program1` assembly. What namespace is `DepartmentConfigurationSection` under? The type attribute should be `type="[namespace], [assembly]"`, so in your case I **think** that should be `type="Statistics.Config.DepartmentConfigurationSection, Program1"`.

Comment: The namespace is `namespace Statistics.Config`. What you mean when said no class in the Program1 assembly ?

Comment: If the namespace is Statistics.Config, then the **fully qualified** name of the class is `Statistics.Config.DepartmentConfigurationSection`. The name of the assembly is `Program1`. So the type attribute should read `type="Statistics.Config.DepartmentConfigurationSection, Program1"`.

Comment: I meant what I said, there's no class named `Program1.Config.DepartmentConfigurationSection` in the `Program1` assembly. The class is named `Statistics.Config.DepartmentConfigurationSection`. :)

Comment: Hi rsbarro, i update my app.config file, If i have another class called **CashSection.cs** equals  DepartmentSection.cs. How i can use from handler both CashCollection and DepartmentsCollection?

            `DepartmentConfigurationSection serviceConfigSection =
            ConfigurationManager.GetSection("s") as DepartmentConfigurationSection;`
            
            `DepartmentConfig serviceConfig = serviceConfigSection.Departments[0];`

Comment: If you have another config section, I think you want to add a another `section` element under `configSections`, and then just add a new config element, similar to how you did with the `s` element.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add class-level attribute at DepartmentCollection class with :

```
[DepartmentCollection(typeof(DepartmentConfig ), AddItemName = "add", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap)]
```

Comment: Please elaborate why you think this is a solution. Just code answers do bring a solution, but not understanding.